# Slow SSAS queries for anything not precalculated

Tags: performance, scope, ssas, mdx

I am having performance issues with the code below. As soon as I take it out it runs really fast. Essentially I am trying to create a Balance to Totals member. Anybody have any ideas on how to speed it up?

A couple of notes: I am using SSAS 2008 Standard Edition. I created Aggregations using the default aggregation usage for all dimensions. I already tried to create a calculated member with the formula below but it didn't play nice with Excel so I had to create a physical member and then overwrite the value using the code below.

```
CREATE HIDDEN SET CURRENTCUBE.[Selected1]
AS [Group].[Attr1].children;    
CREATE HIDDEN SET CURRENTCUBE.[Selected2]
AS [Group].[Attr2].children;            

SCOPE ([Group].[Attr1].&[Balance to Total]); 
    [Group].[Attr1].&[Balance to Total] = [Group].[Attr1].defaultmember - AGGREGATE([Selected1]);  
END SCOPE;
SCOPE ([Group].[Attr2].&[Balance to Total]); 
    [Group].[Attr2].&[Balance to Total] = [Group].[Attr2].defaultmember - AGGREGATE([Selected2]);
END SCOPE;
```